# Python - Изменение элемента двумерного массива

Tags: python, массивы, table

Существует двумерный массив `table` длины и высоты 4 (это не так важно)

```
[
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Я хочу изменить значения элемента с координатами x = 0 и y = 0.

```
def testCell( self, x, y ):
    if 0 <= x < self.N and 0 <= y < self.N :
        self.table[x][y] = 1
```

Однако, вместо массива

```
[
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Я получаю

```
[
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Как правильно изменять значение элемента в двумерном массиве?

Comment: А как вы создали исходный список? Небось копированием списка вложенного?

Comment: `self.table = [[0]*self.N]*self.N`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У в поле `table` хранится ссылка на список, содержащий 4 ссылки на **один** другой список. Создавайте матрицу лучше так: `[[0 for x in range(self.N)] for y in range(self.N)]`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.

Comment: @FeironoX5 [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).